# What's the difference?< for item in list> and <for i in range(len(list))>

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
>>> n = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for item in n:
...     item *= 2
...
>>> print n
[1, 2, 3]
```

I expect the result of the above code to be [2, 4, 6], While obviously it's not. 
Then I tried `for i in range(n)` as follows

```
>>> n = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in range(len(n)):
...     n[i] *= 2
... 
>>> 
>>> n
[2, 4, 6]
```

This seems OK. 
And my question is that, what's the essential difference between these two `for` loop method? What cause the unexpected result above?

Comment: this may help: https://learntofish.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/call-by-object-reference-call-by-sharing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps, the first loop is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(len(n)):
   item = n[i]
   item *= 2
```

In other words, it first binds `item` to the `i`-th element of the list, and then rebinds it to a new object whose value is double that of the `i`-th element. It does not change any of the list's elements.

A good way to implement this loop is using a list comprehension:

```
n = [item * 2 for item in n]
```

Comment: no we should all be using `map` and `reduce` forever! `map(lambda item: functools.reduce(operator.mul, [item, 2]), n)` is *clearly* more easily read

Comment: +1 for mentioning the comprehension.  And "modern" is a pretty loose term here.  They were added in python2.3 or 2.4 (I can't remember off the top of my head).  But those came out ~10 years ago or so?

Comment: @mgilson: Seems like yesterday. :) I've removed the qualification.

Comment: Thanks for all of the helpful answers!! Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the object that represents the current iteration.
Well, actually, you can, but it won't change the object that is held in the list.

> what's the essential difference between these two for loop method?

You iterate over objects in the list in the first example (and try to modify that said object directly - it doesn't change the list's element itself).
And you iterate over the list of integers in the second example (and actually modify the given list's element, so you modify the list content).

Answer (score 0):

`item` is simply a local name. It is originally assigned by the for loop to point to the current element, but if you reassign it to point to something else, that has no effect on the original.

But if you use an index to reference an element in the original list, you can mutate that list to contain different values.

Answer (score 0):

There's no ***assignment*** in `for item in lst`. You're operating on the object itself, which is immutable, so it just creates a new object for you when you do the `*=` call, assigns it to `item`, then throws it away on the next iteration of the loop.

When you do `for i in range(len(lst))` you're ***assigning*** the new object to the `i`th element of `lst`.